# including multiple variables in multiple get variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I have 3 variables, named a, b and c. I want to pass variables into each one of them but i'm having trouble doing so. With 1 variable and 1 get variable it's straight forward like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/example.php?a="+document.domain,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But how will i send for example, document.domain to variable a, document.cookie to variable b and document.URL to variable c all in 1 request?

Comment: what are you trying to say...eidt your question.simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do as you would in a regular URL:

```
var url = "http://example.com/example.php?a="+document.domain + "&b=" + "..." + "&c=" + "...";
```

It's also a good idea to properly encode your values with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use a String.Format

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",String.Format("http://example.com/example.php?a={0}&b={1}&c={2}",document.domain,document.cookie,document.URL),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Is that really JavaScript? String.Format doesn't seem to be available in either Chrome or Firefox (and it's not part of the ES5 standard).

Comment: @bfavaretto
You're right, I either didn't pay attention or the tags changed.